$f$ is continuous and $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L|x - y|$ , $\int_{0}^{T} f(x)dx = 0$, then prove $\sup_{x\in[0,T]}|f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2}LT$.
It's easy to see $\sup_{x\in[0,T]}|f(x)|\leq LT$. But I'm having trouble with the coefficients $ \frac{1}{2}$.
Suppose $f_{\max}(x)=f(a)\geq 0, f_{\min}(x)=f(b)\leq 0$, then
$$|f(a)-f(b)|=|f(a)|+|f(b)|\leq L(|b-a|)\leq LT.$$
$\sup_{x\in[0,T]}|f(x)|=|f(a)|$ or $|f(b)|$. If $|f(a)|=|f(b)|$, Then I could get what I want to prove……But that doesn't always hold. I'm running out of other ideas. Can anyone give me a hint? Much appreciated!

As, $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,T]$, so let there exists an element $a \in [0,T]$ such that $|f(a)| = \sup_{x \in [0,T]} |f(x)|$. Now by the above condition we have $|f(x) - f(a)| \leq L |x - a|$, without loss of generality we can assume that $x > a$, then we have,
$-L(x - a) \leq f(x) - f(a) \leq L(x - a)$, now integrate both side,
$-L\int_{0}^{T}(x - a) \leq \int_{0}^{T}(f(x) - f(a)) \leq L\int_{0}^{T}(x - a)
\\ \implies -LT/2 \leq -LT/2 + a \leq f(a) \leq LT/2 -a \leq LT/2
\\ \implies |f(a)| \leq LT/2
\\ \implies \sup_{x\in[0,T]}|f(x)|\leq LT/2$
